# Java CompletableFuture assigning executor

Tags: java, asynchronous, executorservice, completable-future, concurrent.futures

I am having confusion with defining executor in CompletableFuture. I am not sure how to tell CompletableFuture to run it in that particular executor. Thanks in advance.

```
//Suppose I have an executor
ExecutorService myExecutor=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

//If I create a future like this
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
      //Do something
}, myExecutor); // I can put the executor here and say the future to this executor

//But I do not know where to put executor if I create my future in method style like this

private final CompletableFuture<Void> myMethod(String something) {
  //Do something
    return null;
}

//and use it like this  
.thenCompose(this::myMethod); //How can I specify the executor in this case?
```

Comment: Are you asking about how to run `myMethod` in the executor, which is as simple as using `thenComposeAsync​` instead of `thenCompose`,​ or are you asking about how to control what happens within `myMethod` regarding the returned future, which is impossible?

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you have 3 `CompletableFuture`s that are at play:

1. the one returned by `runAsync()`
2. the one returned by `myMethod()`
3. the one returned by `thenCompose()`

You also have 4 tasks that need to be run:

1. the one passed to `runAsync()` will be executed on the given executor and handle future 1;
2. the one that calls `myMethod()` from `thenCompose()` to create future 2 can be run on any executor, use `thenComposeAsync()` to explicitly choose one;
3. the one that will complete future 2 returned by `myMethod()` – this will be controlled inside `myMethod()` itself;
4. the one that will complete future 3 returned by `thenCompose()` – this is handled internally and will depend on execution order (e.g. if `myMethod()` returns an already completed future, it will also complete the former).

As you can see, several tasks and executors are involved, but you can always control the executors used in dependent stages using `*Async()` variants. The only case where you don't really control it is the 4th case, but it is a cheap operation as long as dependent stages use the `*Async()` variants as well.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
List<Runnable> tasks = getTasks();
CompletableFuture<?>[] futures = tasks.stream()
                               .map(task -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(task, es))
                               .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);
CompletableFuture.allOf(futures).join();    
es.shutdown();
```

Comment: This is interesting.  Is this the only way?  The OP seems to be trying to make a composite kind of `CompletableFuture` first, then submit it.  Whereas you make the individual `CompletableFutures` first, then combine them into a larger "virtual" future object.  Is the OP's way viable?  (It didn't seem to be when I looked at the API.)